# Ada program to detect an end of line

Tags: ada

I was assigned this task as my homework. I have a file which contains lines of text of varying lengths. The program is supposed to write the data onto the screen in precisely the same order in which it is written in the file, yet it fails to do so. To achieve the desired result I tried reading only one character per iteration so as to detect new line characters. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;
WITH Ada.Characters.Latin_1;
USE Ada.Text_IO;

PROCEDURE ASCII_artwork IS
   File : File_Type;
   c : Character;
BEGIN
   Open(File, In_File, "Winnie_The_Pooh.txt");
   WHILE NOT End_Of_File(File) LOOP
      Get(File, C);
      IF (C = Ada.Characters.Latin_1.LF) THEN Put_Line(" "); ELSE
         Put(C);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
   Close(File);
END ASCII_Artwork;
```

Comment: What is the result you get ?

Comment: Moreover, LF is line feed only and depending on the input file, there may be need of CR too.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at Get_Line too 

Comment: Get_Line() would require me to assume that every line is of the same length, which is not the case. I have already discovered that I could use End_Of_Line(File) to do the job. Are there any additional solutions? Previously, the program would only output the contents of the file without ending lines as intended.

Comment: There are several versions of Get_Line. Especially one you could use in a declaration block

Comment: Take a good took at the function form of Get_Line; and learn tat you can declare a String and initialise it, in a Declare block in a loop. The String gets its length from the initialisation, which galls Get_Line.

Comment: `Get_Line` does not require that all lines be the same length. I suggest you familiarize yourself with the definitions of the basic `Ada.Text_IO` operations at ARM A.10 and following (http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10.html). Annex A presents the entire Ada standard library and should be understood by every software engineer using Ada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each file, the Ada runtime maintains a fictitious "cursor". This is not the typical file position cursor (index), but one that indicates the position on a page, line, etc. (see also [RM A.10 (7)](http://ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10.html)). This is somewhat of an inheritance from the early versions of Ada.

`Get` stems from this same era and is expected to update the location of this cursor when some particular control characters are being read (e.g. an end-of-line mark). If `Get` reads such such a control character, it will only use it to update the cursor (internally) and then continue to read a next character (see also [RM A.10.7 (3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html)). You'll therefore never detect an end-of-line mark when using `Get`.

This behavior, however, has some uncomfortable consequence: if a file ends with a sequence of control characters, then `Get` will keep reading those characters and hit the end of the file causing an `End_Error` exception.

You can, of course, catch this exception and handle it, but such a construct is dubious as having a sequence of control characters at the end of a file is actually not such an abnormal case (and hence dubious if worth an exception). As a programmer, however, you cannot change this behavior: it's defined by the language and the language will not be changed because it has been decided to keep Ada (highly) backwards compatible (which in itself is understandable given its field of application).

Hence, in your case, if you want stick to a character-by-character processing approach, I would suggest to move away from `Get` and instead use (for example) streams to perform I/O as in the example below.

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams; use Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams;

procedure ASCII_artwork IS
   File   : File_Type;
   Input  : Stream_Access;
   Output : Stream_Access;
   C      : Character;
begin

   Open (File, In_File, "Winnie_The_Pooh.txt");

   Input  := Stream (File);
   Output := Stream (Standard_Output);

   while not End_Of_File (File) loop      
      Character'Read (Input, C);
      Character'Write (Output, C);      
   end loop;

   Close(File);

end ASCII_Artwork;
```

Output is as expected (i.e. the content of this [the file](http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/uvw/winnie_the_pooh.txt) at ascii-art.de).

*NOTE: Check the [source code of the GNAT runtime](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/a-textio.adb;h=b36d28b4dc827ce3287ac065d967118b421ff073;hb=HEAD#l483) to actually see how `Get` works internally (focus on the loop at the end).*

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If you turn in this solution, I suspect it will not be well received, parly because you didn't do it yourself, and partly because your instructor wants you to use `Get_Line` and `Put_Line`, and this uses concepts you have not been introduced to yet.

Answer (score 3):

As explained by DeeDee, text inputs are buffered linewise in Ada. The idea is to be able to read two integers on the same line. For consistency sake (the designers of Ada are picky on that...), Get(File, C) does the same. It is not practical in your case. Fortunately, Ada 95 has introduced Get_Immediate, to solve precisely that issue.

Otherwise, as suggested by Frédéric, you could use the *function* Get_Line to absorb Winnie_The_Pooh.txt line by line seamlessly. By the way, the Get_Line method will convert the different end-of-line conventions automatically.

Comment: `Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line` does not convert different end-of-line conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Line terminators in `Ada.Text_IO` are a concept, not a character or sequence of characters in the file. (Although most commonly used file systems implement them as characters or sequences of characters in the file, there exist file systems that do not.) Line terminators must therefore be manipulated using the operations in the package. For reading, `End_Of_Line` checks to see if the cursor is at a line terminator, `Skip_Line` skips the next line terminator, and `Get_Line` may skip a line terminator. For writing, `New_Line` and `Put_Line` write line terminators.

For your problem, the canonical solution is to use the `Get_Line` function to read lines, and `Put_Line` to output the lines read.

Comment: And I guess by "file systems that do not" you refer to e.g. [record-oriented filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem) as used on mainframes (MVS, z/OS, etc.)? Were these kind of operating systems (or more precise, their method of storing data) the driver for this abstraction in Ada 83? Or were there other considerations? I find it hard to obtain information on these kind of topics. The [Ada 83 rationale](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/Welcome.html) doesn't really seem to cover the actual use cases that were on the table at that time.

Comment: Ada was developed for the US DoD in the late 1970s and early 1980s to become the only language used in their systems. As such `Text_IO` had to abstract the concepts of text files to be usable on all such systems that had text files. Similarly, the ARM refers to "storage units" rather than "bytes" because many systems in use at the time weren't byte oriented.